# One liner in Python needed to replace a for loop with if-else to change values in a dataframe

Tags: python, list, performance, dataframe, vectorization

I have a medium sized dataframe (length ~ 200k rows) where I'm trying to replace a column's values to either 0 or 1 depending on each cell's value:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.Column[i]<=3:
        df.Column[i]=1
    else:
        df.Column[i]=0
```

But this is taking a long time (5-10 minutes). So, I am trying to find a faster, vectorized approach to do this. I tried the following way of doing a list comprehension, but it doesn't work:

```
[df.Column[i]=1 if df.Column[i]<=3 else if df.Column[i]=0 for i in range(len(df))]
```

It gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at the `=` symbol. And even if it did work, I doubt if it'd make it significantly faster (as its doing the same thing as before - comparing elements one by one and changing them).

So, what would be a faster, more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Replace all your code with `df.Column = (df.Column <= 3).astype(int)` and let me know if that's better.

Comment: @coldspeed Yeah, this works! Thanks :) Magical how how the for loop takes 5-10 mins, and this line does it instantaneously.